# Not enough input arguments error in the imread statement

Tags: matlab

```
function img3bitcolor = img2coe3(image_in,file_coe)
%SUMPROD Creat file .coe from image PNG or JPEG
% image file is 3 bit RGB => 8 colors
% Creat file coe
img = imread(image_in);%Read image
height = size(img,1);%Take height image
width  = size(img,2);%Take width image
s = fopen(file_coe,'wb');%Open file coe with mode write
fprintf(s,'%s\n','; VGA Memory Map ');
fprintf(s,'%s\n','; .COE file with bit coefficients ');
fprintf(s,';Height : %d, Width : %d\n\n',height,width);
fprintf(s,'%s\n','; Data image is bit => coefficients is 2');
fprintf(s,'%s\n','memory_initialization_radix=2;');
fprintf(s,'%s\n','memory_initialization_vector=');
img3bitcolor = img;
end
```

After running the program:

> Not enough input arguments.
> Error in `img2coe3` (line 6)
>
> ```
> img = imread(image_in);%Read image
> ```

Comment: Have you created a file called `imread.m` by chance?

Comment: i have never shown imread.m

Comment: Type `which imread` in MATLAB, see what it says. I think you have overridden the function with a different one that needs more inputs.

Comment: Are you by any chance just pressing run on this function file? If no then what input arguments are you using for running `img2coe3`?

Comment: can you edit your post to share what the variable `image_in` is?